# Can't save settings after copying site to new server

Tags: 7

I just recently copied a Drupal 7 site from one server to another, everything looks like it works fine except that I cannot save any settings.

Here are some other symptoms:

- I can't disable or enable modules
- Overlay doesn't work
- Once I log out, I can't log back in
- When trying to log back in with the wrong criteria, I don't get a message about the user/pass being wrong
- admin_toolbar doesn't work (except immediately after clearing cache via drush)
- Status report doesn't show anything being wrong

I've got varnish running on the server and I'm not quite sure if that would have anything to do with it.

Comment: Bayo, if you found the solution, please post it as an answer to the question and mark it as accepted when you can.  This way it will be easier for future visitors to quickly and easily find the answer:)

Comment: Good point, I'm posting what I did.  I gotta wait 21 hrs to accept though

Comment: Can you explain the methods you used for copying your site over? I'm interested in figuring out the best migration strategy from dev to staging/live.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had to enable Mod Rewrite.
`sudo a2enmod rewrite`
If you're having this issue, also check that your .htaccess files copied over to the new server (I've wasted countless hours chasing this).

Comment: Just copied a drupal7 site into a vscode .devcontainer, and that problem occured.
This was a fix.