# Unable save/update any content after migrating from local to production

Tags: migrations

This is the first time I have made my Drupal site live on a production server (Ubuntu ls 10.04).

These are the steps I did:

1. Zip the entire webroot folder
2. Upload to the production server
3. Extract the contents into the webroot
4. Take db dump from local server
5. Dump into the production server
6. Update the production's Drupal admin password

I do not have a problem viewing the contents, but I am unable to save any content including the configuration settings such as Site information. It doesn't throw any error message or update the content.

What other steps might I have missed?

Comment: Does your settings.php have correct database settings?

Comment: Did also .htaccess get copied? Do you have mod_rewrite working on the server?

Comment: Yes, I have .htaccess file copied. Not sure what is mod-rewirte?

Comment: Please add mod_rewrite in answer. Thanks a million it solved

Comment: Answer below indicates this is a dup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check mod_rewrite (server module) and .htaccess (configuration files in Drupal installation, which easily can be left behind when copying) which take care of lot of the URL and path functionality.

Read more from https://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls

Credits to this question: 
[Can't save settings after copying site to new server](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20713/cant-save-settings-after-copying-site-to-new-server)

Answer (score 0):

Find these lines in your .htaccess and uncomment RewriteBase /

# If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
 # uncomment the following line:
 RewriteBase /